# Keep-Alive socket with HTTP server under C# (.net) how to send several queries?

Tags: c#, sockets, http, keep-alive

Noob question.
So i try this code to call http server for resource many times on same socket:

```
 public void TryReuseSameSocket(){
            var addr = Dns.GetHostAddresses("stackoverflow.com");
            var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                // i thought that i must to use this option
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, 1);
                socket.Connect(addr, 80);
                var bigbuff = new byte[10000];
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    //now i try to call some URL many times without socket closing
                    var buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /help/badges HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");
                    socket.Send(buff);
                    var reciveCount = 0;
                    var totalCount = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        reciveCount = socket.Receive(bigbuff);
                        totalCount += reciveCount;
                        if (0 == reciveCount) break;
                    }
                    //only first call will proceed, all others will not have a result
                    Assert.AreNotEqual(0,totalCount);

                }

            }
            finally
            {
                socket.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

But only first call proceed, all others return no data at all in recieve.

How to reuse socket with HTTP server correctly.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Use WebClient , HttpWebRequest or HttpClient ?

Comment: Any particular reason for using a `Socket` instead of a higher level abstraction?

Comment: Where are some reasones. We had already implementation with HttpWebRequest and HttpClient. 
1) Even on not keep-alive socket with quick-made http protocol parser we gain performance boost 20% with less memory (we have no needs to handle all features of HTTP/S, but have needs in performance - some components works spider
2) We trys SuperSockets but it still require hand-made implementation of HttpProtocol and cause great chunk of dependencies and not usefull code for us

Comment: 3) We work hard with REST API-s of some internal services so it can be much efficient to have more native handshake/conversation support  for them without addition layer over HTTP parsing
4) We need support both .NET and Mono editions of product. So by experience - only on Socket layer (especially at server side) we have stable identical behavior, more perepherical classes (WebClient and so on, especially HttpListener ) seems to be not identical on those platforms. We see some risks in it.

Comment: So we decide to try migrate our services and clients to self-written  wrappers over socket layer. But not being much competence in network  internals have some troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the stream until it is closed by the remote side. It makes sense that after that point you won't get any data.

You need to make the server keep the connection alive. This is done by setting a keep alive HTTP header. You seem to be doing that.

With HTTP keep alive the server will set the `Content-Length` header to tell you how many bytes to read. Read exactly that many bytes. After that, send the next request.

TCP keep alives (`SocketOptionName.KeepAlive`) have nothing to do with HTTP keep alives. Remove that code.

Comment: Thank you for TCP.KeepAlive suggestion, thought that it is required on lower level for HTTP.KeepAlive.

Of course here U see special sample for stackoverflow (and here Connection: Keep-Alive is sent to server). 

In working code we have NetworkStream over Socket, we write request, catch Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding: chunked, and then read stream to the end. 

But it doesn't work , just first request, all subsequent - nothing is back .

Comment: May be U can suggest how to read NetworkStream while it will be closed by remote side? For now we just read exactly content-length or exactly chunks before "0" chunk. Then we try to send other request and stream became always "not DataAvailable". So we start to do "magic things" - Thread.Sleep(10), addition read of NetworkStream before next request and control that lenght == 0, check response headers and see that server's header Connection is Keep-Alive too... How to do it well???

Comment: @ФагимСадыков When read returns 0 bytes you have already lost. The server has closed the connection. Nothing you can do at this point.; Hard to tell what you'Re doing wrong without seeing the current version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition the mistakes in my other answer you are not instructing the server to keep the connection alive. The proper header value is `keep-alive`. That's why the server closes the connection.

Answer (score -2):

Thx. Now I have found solution:

1) Don't forget check socket.Available to decide is stream read to end, checking of stream.Read(...) == 0 or Recive(...)==0 is not real thing

2) Don't trust Internet - some servers return Keep-Alive but it's not true - connection is opened, but all subrequests fails

3) Snippet in question is working if reading logic will looks like

```
while (socket.Available != 0)
{
    socket.Receive(bigbuff);
}
```

4) It's not 100% always good (u need check some other socket things to controll reading), but on sites with real Keep-Alive support it works well.

Comment: Available does *not* indicate how much data is to come. It indicates how much data happens to be buffered. This number can increase at any time. Your retry loop in (3) accomplishes nothing. In fact, now the code is incorrect because it will randomly stop reading at some point. Just delete the loop.

Comment: All things get not 100% but checking of Available is more efficient than checking length of recieve. "Read to end" was not main goal of question, and now in working code it made by cross-checking on Available, Connected, expected length (by Content-Length or chunked) with connection timeout on unexpected EOF. Main question was about Keep-Alive that "not working" - and as it was tested on some internet resources  - server header Connection: Keep-Alive doesn't always mean that server really do... Now solved - on empty response we forcely reconnect.